# Nulling varbinary without logging the full value

Tags: sql, sql-server

If anyone has a suggestion for a better title, be my guest

Background: I have an images table that stores photos from thousands of orders, but once those orders are complete/cancelled I want to remove the image (which is stored as a varbinary) without deleting the entire row, so that I don't exceed the 10GB SQL express limit

The reason I don't want to delete the row is because I have another table with some images properties (crop area, brightness, etc) and if for whatever reason the image needs to be restored (simple API call to another server), it will just update the existing record in the images table, and I still have access to the properties for that image that are kept in the properties table

So here's what a query could look like

```
UPDATE images
SET images.image = NULL
FROM images
INNER JOIN orders on orders.order_id = images.order_id
WHERE orders.status = 'COMPLETED'
```

And it takes forever, as it could be nulling up to a few GB of varbinary data a a time (orders are done in bulks, not one by one). That's all then kept in the transaction log. It can take my machine with a SSD up to a minute to complete that, and the production machine's HDD several minutes.

Is there a way I can do a simple transaction log per query, rather than setting the entire log to simple mode? Or a better way of deleting the varbinary values?

Thanks

Comment: Don't store images in a database, keep them on the filesystem - especially if you're concerned about db size.

Comment: DavidG Is correct. If that's not possible, you can maybe try creating a new table from the original table without the unwanted images , rename it, and replace it with the old one. I don't know how much faster it will be though.

Comment: @DavidG not suitable for my needs, this is running on a service that will do a lot of transformations on images, print them,, generate previews, convert to base64 to be sent to a printer, sent over tcp to multiple clients etc, etc. Possibly all of the above at the same time, to multiple clients. Storing on the filesystem caused way too many issues

Comment: That makes no sense. You're still keeping them on disk even if it's in the database.

Comment: And if they are on a windows filesystem with the language I'm using,only one function can access the image at once. I can argue all day with you, it does not work, end of story.

Comment: And that language is?

Comment: What you'd need is an equivalent to `TRUNCATE TABLE` -- a minimally logged version of changing the column. To my knowledge, that doesn't exist, nor can I imagine this ever making it high on the priority list (it's not impossible, but not exactly trivial to implement either). If deleting the row is actually faster (is it? I doubt it, as that row would still need to be logged) you could do a `SELECT/DELETE/INSERT` in a transaction, copying over the columns you wish to keep (this presumes no foreign keys get in the way and you may have to use `identity_insert`).

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you could actually leverage `TRUNCATE/DROP TABLE` -- by storing each image in its single-row, single-column table. (SQL Server has a limit of 2B objects per database, which won't limit you in practice.) Obviously, accessing the images will be vastly less convenient this way, you need dynamic SQL, and you'll have to abandon Management Studio (because it will hate you for all those tables) but if you were absolutely hell-bent on using the database and not the file system, this would be one way to abuse your environment to make it possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This still suffers the issue of having a massive DB file and needing to shrink it regularly, which as I'm sure you know, is a little bit naughty.

Comment: @DavidG: store the table(s) in their own file group(s) and the issue of shrinking can be contained as much as we please. Also, while shrinking is not advisable in general, it's also not the end of the world, and we *are* doing this whole thing to avoid a file size limit, so something's gotta give.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, there's plenty of workarounds, but I think my advice to keep the files out of the DB still stands.

Comment: @DavidG: Absolutely, and if I wasn't clear in endorsing that solution, let me ameliorate that: consider storing your files in the file system so you don't have to fight the transactional logging of your transactionally logged database system, and if there are problems with that, consider solving *those* instead. But supposing you've done *all that*...